# Laravel 5 in subdirectory

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, subdirectory

So, i need Laravel 5 to be installed and running in subdirectory (Laravel 5.3), i tried everything online, i even tested the .htaccess i have written to redirect from the subdirectory to public folder in that subdirectory (which works fine in online testers), but yet, when i open:

```
http://example.com/subdirectory/route
```

it doesnt work, when i try

```
http://example.com/subdirectory/public/route
```

then everything is fine ...

So, is there anyone that can help me out resolving this issue? 
Here is the .htaccess im currently using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ subdirectory/public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried this alot and mostly failed. However it is actually fine to fail because it's highly insecure to host it in a public subdirectory. The best solution to me was to host it on a subdomain (if your provider gives you the option to create one)

Comment: For one of our projects we just symlinked the directory name to the public folder of the Laravel project.